# How to create a looped linked list with this approach in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have the following classes:

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :data, :next

  def initialize(data = nil)
    @data = data
  end
end

class LinkedList
  def initialize(items)
    @head = Node.new(items.shift)
    items.inject(@head) {|last, data| last.next = Node.new(data) }
  end
end
```

So I can have LinkedLists by doing this:

```
ll = LinkedList.new([1,2,3,4])
```

I find this approach pretty clean (having a LinkedList class that wraps several Node objects). However, I am concerned on how I would be able to create a looped linked list (the next element of last element would be pointing at first element).

How should I modify this implementation in order to be able to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just store the current "next" node as it's created outside the `inject` proc, overwriting the previous node so that when you're done `inject`ing, you have a handle to the actual last node in the list. Then link it's `next` to `@head`.

```
def initialize(items)
  @head = Node.new(items.shift)
  items.inject(@head) {|last, data| @last = last.next = Node.new(data) }
  @last.next = @head
end
```